# panel height size calc on pageinit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

please take a look at the following screenshot:

[image: wrong layout]

The **first time** opening the page the height of the right panel isn't calculated correctly and doesnt fill the whole `<div data-role="content">` section.

Opening or clicking into the page seems to trigger the pageshow or some other event and the logo is centered in the middle and the panels height is calculated correctly to height 100% of the content div.

the right layout would be this:

[image: correct layout]

*Where is my problem here?*

I read that the exact pageheight is known first in the pageshow event of jqm. the height of the content-div or the panel(?) seems to be calculated too late. is there a possibility to trigger  an update manually?

Is this my error or do i miss here something completly different? Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: try calling `$.mobile.resetActivePageHeight();` on `pageshow`. Add some code pls.

Comment: Try to use another loading event like `$(window).load(function(){ /*your stuff here*/ })` to delay the execution of the event

Comment: @Omar you nailed it! i would vote up this answer 10 times, this was bothering me for weeks...

Comment: You're welcome. I updated my answer with a tiny hint :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with dynamic items call `$.mobile.resetActivePageHeight();` on `pageshow`.

Moreover, `$.mobile.resetActivePageHeight();` function can be called anytime, especially when appending header/footer to a page dynamically.